# GIS Web based (php) offline

Tags: web, gis

I want to create GIS Server on my local server (Web Based). What Engine will I use? But in my network no Internet access. So I have a lot of mif file. And I want to display on my browser. How could it be?

Answer (score 1):

MapServer is the most supported open source web mapping server.

http://www.mapserver.org/

It supports both PHP and MapInfo files.